# Additional information: External table is not in the expected format. in CSV File

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I'm working in c# windows application i done a project that is to import data from csv file to mysql server. i got may links to import data's but when i try that i m having the issues

> Additional information: External table is not in the expected format

in my code

I'm working in Microsoft Visual studio 2015 , .NET Framework 4.5.2.

codes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Text files | *.csv";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName;
                fileName = dlg.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = fileName;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                string path = textBox1.Text;

                string name = "";
                string age = "";
                string class = "";
                string sec = "";
                string address = "";
                string phno = "";

                OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                my_con.Open();

                OleDbCommand icmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", my_con);

                OleDbDataReader dr = icmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    name = dr[0].ToString();
                    age = dr[1].ToString();
                    class = dr[2].ToString();
                    sec = dr[3].ToString();
                    address = dr[4].ToString();
                    phno = dr[6].ToString();

                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=10.65.43.687;" +
               "DATABASE=student;" +
               "UID=root;" +
               "PASSWORD=root123");
                    con.Open();

                    MySqlCommand icmmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO student(name,age,class,sec,address,phno)VALUES(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)", con);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", Name);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", Age);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", Class);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", Section);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", Address);
                    icmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", Phone);
                    icmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("data Imported");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {

            }           
            MessageBox.Show("Upload Successfull!");
        }
```

Error in the line:

```
 my_con.Open();
```

guys help me to solve my problem please.

Comment: Connection string problem : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @x... Its an excel connection string. but i am using csv file is that i need to use excel connection?

Comment: For csv file, just use File.ReadAllLines, it is easier. Then use string.Split to split the line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes to your connection string

```
string _name = string.Empty;

        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if(OFD.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _name = OFD.FileName;
        }

        var pathstring = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_name);
        con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+pathstring+";Extended Properties='Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited;'";
        con.Open();

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from "+System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_name), con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt); con.Close();
```

This will help you open a connection to your csv file & read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code to Convert data of Excel (.xlx,.xlsx,.csv) to DataTable.

```
private DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string filename) {
   using (System.IO.Stream inputStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename)) {
     using (Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelEngine excelEngine = new Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelEngine()) { 
      Syncfusion.XlsIO.IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel; Syncfusion.XlsIO.IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream); 
      Syncfusion.XlsIO.IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]; 
      DataTable dataTable = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames); 
      return dataTable; 
      } 
   } 
}
```